# ACPI Error: No handler for Region [RAM_] ((____ptrval____)) [EmbeddedControl] 20190816/evregion-127

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, systemd, acpi, initramfs

I am getting following error messages on 20.04 Focal I tried finding out if it is answered I could not find a satisfactory answer so this Query I am attaching the Image with other errors as well ( Just in case they are related )

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/603589/focal-fossa-acpi-error-no-handler-for-region-ram-ptrval-embe

Can somebody take a look and advise please ?

[image]